# Why local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have changes to `Makefile` in different places.

[image: screenshot: "git diff" showing local changes]

[image: screenshot: "git stash show -p" showing different changes]

**Why I still get error?**

```
$ git stash pop
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Makefile
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
```

My changes are not intersect. So I expect they should be merged without any problem.

Comment: you need to stage your local changes. Post that you can try git stash pop, git would attempt AUTO merge then.

Comment: @Prasanna: I know what to do from the error message. But **why** I am required to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are technical issues, which prevent `git stash pop` to use the index as freely as other commands (since it actually modifies the index itself), and to avoid a complicated logic around the `stash apply` mechanism, to this point, `git stash pop` simply refuses to apply changes on an "unclean" file.

---

The simple way around this is to create a commit with said files :

```
git add Makefile
git commit -m "wip"
git stash pop

# ... fix stuff if needed ...

# after stash application : you can jump one commit backwards
git reset --soft HEAD^   # if you want to keep stuff in the index
git reset HEAD^          # if you can reset the index too
```

Comment: Would be nice if there will be `autostash` option. Like it is for `pull`

Comment: stashing in A to allow to apply stash B is not really a solution, IMHO ... :) :) :)